# Invoke AWS Lambda SNS event only after SQS subscription on same topic has been processed

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns, aws-lambda

I would like to implement an Amazon SNS topic which first delivers messages to a SQS queue that is a subscriber on the topic, and then executes an AWS Lambda function that is also a subscriber on the same topic. The Lambda function can then read messages from the SQS queue and process several of them in parallel (hundreds).

My question is whether there is any way to guarantee that messages sent to the SNS topic would first be delivered to the SQS queue, and only then to the Lambda function?

The purpose of this is to scale to a large number of messages without having to execute the Lambda function separately for every single message.

Comment: Did not get you. Lambda function is subscriber to the topic and also polling the queue that has the same set of messages? Also remember you cannot goto sqs and then ask for a specific message. So how do you intend to design your lambda function to get the same message from queue?

Comment: In my use case it does not matter which messages the Lambda function will receive. It will process whatever messages are buffered in the SQS queue. E.g. if 100 messages have been queued up before the first Lambda function invocation is called, then it will process all of them. The other 99 function invocations will quit immediately since the queue is already empty. My worry is that if I send only one SNS message, the Lambda invocation occurs before the message gets to SQS, and the queue will look empty to the function.

Comment: If all you want is a lambda function to run whenever you send a notification out then why not subscribe a lambda function to sns itself. Why worry about sqs at all?

Comment: I have two worries in the case without SQS:
- If the Lambda function fails, some messages will go unprocessed, so I'd like them to stay in SQS
- The solution won't scale, if one Lambda function invocation can only process a single message at a time (there's a limit of 100 invocations in parallel).

Comment: Yes, your assumption about `Lambda` failure is correct. It's much easier to handle messages stored inside `SQS` subscribed to `SNS Topic`.

Comment: @Kennu - you can remove the 100 invocation limit. They say that it's only there so you don't accidentally rack up a multi-thousand dollar bill if you don't know what you're doing. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/limits.html

Comment: Is any harm done if the Lambda function were to occasionally run prior to the message being inserted into SQS. Is it good enough for this to be the case most of the time and unsupported? I believe it will "just work", but I could see that changing since I don't see any documentation for sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is currently not possible with one `SNS Topic`. If you subscribe your `Lambda` to a `SNS Topic` that particular `Lambda` gets executed each time that `SNS Topic` receives a message, in parallel.

Solution might be to have two `SNS Topics` and publish messages to the first one and have your `SQS` subscribe to it. After successful submission of messages to this first topic you could send a message to the second `SNS Topic` to execute your `Lambda` to process messages the first `SNS Topic` stored to `SQS`.

Another possible solution might be the above, you could just send some periodic message to the second topic to run the subscribed `Lambda`. This would allow you to scale your `Lambda SQS Workers`.

Comment: Do you think that routing the message through a second SNS topic would give any guarantee that the parallel SQS message has already been delivered? Or would it still be a matter of luck.

Comment: You should send message to the second `SNS Topic` after you've published all messages to the first one. Messages sent to the first `SNS Topic` are immediately available in the `SQS`. Once the second topic receives your message, it immediately starts `Lambda` which will process this queue.

Comment: Ah yes thanks, now I got it. First I thought you meant just to route the message from SNS to a second SNS topic. The solution I originally ended up with was, in fact, to first push all the messages directly to SQS and then trigger the Lambda function by a single message sent to SNS.

Comment: Yeah, that's very similar solution.

Comment: @Kennu - sorry for digging up such an old thread. How is this solution working out for you? I'm thinking about doing the same. Actually, I'm trying to decide if it's necessary or if I should just go directly from SNS to Lambda, skipping sqs

Comment: @joshblour skipping SQS would mean you loose a message when there's no SNS subscriber for any reason or when the execution fails

Answer (score 4):

For this purpose, triggering the lambda could be better and efficient if used from a cloud watch alert. With the cloud watch alert set at a buffer limit on the SQS, that could fire the lambda to start and process the full queue.

Answer (score 0):

Subscribing both an SQS queue and a Lambda function to an SNS topic is a good way to have your Lambda function process SNS messages with low latency. I've tested this process just now. With every attempt the lambda function is invoked after the SQS message is inserted. I wouldn't expect this to always be the case, but it fixes the latency problem as best I am willing to measure. It's not guaranteed and you will need a CloudWatch scheduled event to pick up any missed messages.